# 1000 numbers are chosen at random

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

1000 numbers are chosen at random and independently from 1-1000.

What is the probability that 7 is chosen five times?

I think that $\frac{1}{1000}$ is the probability that 7 is chosen at any step. So the probability that it is chosen in five places is $\frac{1}{1000}^5$

So the probability that 7 is chosen five times is $\frac{1}{1000}^5*_{1000}C_{995}$ because we have to consider the others 995 places.

Is that correct?

Comment: Note that you have to ensure that $7$ is not chosen in the remaining $995$ spots. As a hint,  observe that the number of $7$'s follows a binomial distribution.

Comment: @KurtlandChua right, thank you! So for this same exercise the probability that 4 Or 6 are chosen 10 times would be P(4 chosen ten times) +P(6 chosen 10 times) - P(4 and 6 chosen ten times each)? And the number of 4's and 6's would correspond to binomial distributions too?

Comment: Yes, but do be careful - the intersection of the two events is slightly more complicated